# LINQ Order DataTable based on string date

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a dataTable with column "date" which has dates in string format.
I can't sort it with LINQ.

Table example

```
ID     date
1      20.02.2022
2      15.05.2021
3      03.07.2019
```

This is the LINQ expression I have so far, but it always says **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**

```
(From x In dt.AsEnumerable()
Order By Convert.ToDateTime(x("date").ToString)
Select x).CopyToDataTable
```

I've also tried this, but with the same result

```
(From x In dt.AsEnumerable()
Order By DateTime.ParseExact(x("date").ToString,"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Select x).CopyToDataTable
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: If the date column in the datatable was an actual date datatype, it seems like all your problems would go away.

Comment: "What am I missing?" That you should store dates as dates, and not some fancy representation? You are finding out some of the reasons that most people will tell you to use correct data-types in a database.

Comment: The information from the dataTable is extracted from an application based on a selector, the only way to store these is as string.

Comment: Why would you tell your code to parse the dates using "dd/MM/yyyy" when your example data looks like "20.02.2022"? How about telling it to use the actual format of your data?

Comment: *"the only way to store these is as string"*. That is objectively false. If you can parse the data to sort it then you could parse it before storing it and then store as actual dates instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easy; use a strongly typed datatable. It can still be used like a normal datatable but it's less of a pig to work with

- add a new DataSet type of file to your project
- call it eg MyProjectNameHereDataSet
- right click the design surface, choose Add DataTable, give it a nice name like Concerts
- right click the DataTable and Add Column
- call it ID, make it an int
- add another column, call it something more interesting than Date - ConcertDate perhaps. Avoid naming columns words that are keywords or types
- make it a DateTime type

This visual designer effectively just wrote you a class with two properties, int Id and DateTime ConcertDate, and it made a datatable capable of holding them.

When you're loading your data into your table, do the parsing then (you'll have to now it's strongly typed). It is more efficient to do so than doing it every time you query

```
Dim dt = new ConcertsDataTable()

'in a loop? Some api call? Wherever the data comes from
dt.AddConcertsRow(theId, DateTime.ParseExact(theDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Now you can LINQ it more nicely; no need for AsEnumerabke, or digging column names out by string and casting them etc

```
dt.OrderBy(Function(r) r.ConcertDate)
```

Nice:

```
Dim totalAttendancePast = 0
For Each ro in dt
  If ro.ConcertDate < DateTime.Now Then totalAttendancePast += ro.Attendance
Next ro
```

Nasty:

```
For Each ro as DataRow in dt.Rows
  If DateTime.ParseExact(ro("ConcertDate"), "dd.MM.yyyy") < DateTime.Now Then totalAttendancePast += DirectCast(ro("Attendance"), Integer)
Next ro
```

Nicer:

```
dt.
  Where(Function(r) r.ConcertDate < DateTime.Now).
  Sum(Function(r) r.Attendance)
```

Nastier:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().
  Where(Function(r) DateTime.ParseExact(ro("ConcertDate"), "dd.MM.yyyy") < DateTime.Now).
  Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Integer)(Attendance))
```

You can use this strongly typed datatable anywhere you would use a normal datatable - you can still access it by string column names etc if you desperately wanted to:

```
someDatagridview.DataSource = dt

someDataAdapter.Fill(dt)

MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows(0)("Id").ToString())
```

But it's very helpful to have intellisense be able to guide you and stay in strongly typed land:

```
MessageBox.Show(dt.First().Id.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, I was using "dd/MM/yyyy" when my data comes in as "20.02.2021".
I used "dd.MM.yyyy" and it works.